# Reorder Observable Collection Binding in WinUI

Tags: c#, winui-3

I have a few issues with binding an **ObservableCollection** using **WinUI 3**:

**(a)** When the collection changes (an item is added, removed), the ListView is not updated.

**(b)** Upon reordering the ListView (using the control itself), the ListView does not keep the new order.

**Class Definitions**

```
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Xml.Linq;

public class Standards 
{
   public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
   private void NotifyPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
   {
    PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
   }

private ObservableCollection<Standard> _Collection;

public ObservableCollection<Standard> Collection {
    get => _Collection; 
    set { if (_Collection != value) { _Collection = value; 
        NotifyPropertyChanged("Description"); } } 
    }
}
public class Standard : INotifyPropertyChanged
 {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        private void NotifyPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
        public Standard() { }
        public Standard(XElement e)
        {
            Name = e.Attribute("name").Value;
            Description = e.Attribute("description").Value;
        }
        public Standard(string standard, string description)
        {
            Name = standard;
            Description = description;
        }
        private string _Description;
        private string _name;
        public string Name { get => _name;  set { if (_name != value){ _name = value; NotifyPropertyChanged("Name"); } } 
   }
        
        public string Description { get => _Description; set { if (_Description != value) { _name = value; NotifyPropertyChanged("Description"); } } }
 }
```

**WinUI XAML**

```
<ListView x:Name="lvStandards"
 Grid.Row="2"
 Margin="5" 
 CanReorderItems="True"
 ReorderMode="Enabled"
 AllowDrop="True"
 ItemsSource="{x:Bind viewModel.Standards.Collection, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
```

Comment: So how do you add, remove and re-order items? Your code sample doesn't tell.

Answer (score 0):

On my test it works as expected.  I think there is something wrong with your binding.  If I bind at run-time:

`lvData.ItemsSource = standards.Collection;`

all works well and the collection gets reordered.  Adding items to the collection also makes them appear in the list view.

Please try to bind at run-time.

Answer (score 0):

It might be just missing in this question but at least you need to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` in your Standards class and change the argument at your Collection's `NotifyPropertyChanged` to "Collection".

```cs
public class Standards : INotifyPropertyChanged // HERE
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void NotifyPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    private ObservableCollection<Standard> _Collection;

    public ObservableCollection<Standard> Collection
    {
        get => _Collection;
        set
        {
            if (_Collection != value)
            {
                _Collection = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("Collection");  // HERE
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Also take a look at the [CommunityToolkit MVVM](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/communitytoolkit/mvvm/introduction) NuGet package. It will make your life easier and will make your code small and clean.

```cs
[ObservableObejct]
public partial class Standards
{
    [ObservableProperty]
    private ObservableCollection<Standard> _Collection;
}
```